# List of integers to pairs of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of integers like this

```
numbers = [1, 5, 7, 19, 22, 55]
```

I want to have a function that takes this as input and gives me a list of paired tuples that should contain the numbers as `(1,5), (5,7), (7,19)` and so on.

Kindly suggest.

I have tried using for loops. Didn't get expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Python 3.10 you can use [itertools.pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)

```
from itertools import pairwise

numbers = [1, 5, 7, 19, 22, 55]
list(pairwise(numbers)) # [(1, 5), (5, 7), (7, 19), (19, 22), (22, 55)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [(numbers[i],numbers[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(numbers)-1)]
```

This should do the trick: loop over all elements in the list numbers. You loop until the one to last element, since otherwise you would walk out of the array (get an index error).

Comment: Similarly, you could use `zip` to achieve a similar result: `[(n1, n2) for n1, n2 in zip(numbers, numbers[1:])]`